# How to determine volatility for private company for Black-Scholes

Tags: volatility

I am trying to determine the volatility to use Black-Scholes to value some warrants for a private company. Very few comps are public or they are large diversified businesses.  Any thoughts on how to do this or ranges to start from?
Thanks
Connie Dubois

Comment: You are facing a similar issue than this post:
http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/20721/how-to-compute-the-volatility-for-the-mertons-model-for-private-firm/20722#20722

Answer (score -4):

There is an easy method to calculate volatility if you have a historic time series of price data. First, obtain the standard deviation of the log returns.

---

Imagine you have these observed prices,

> {30.00, 31.70, 27.38, 27.50, 23.96, 23.30, 30.63, 24.04}

Calculate the log return,

> *ln*(31.70/30.00), *ln*(27.38/31.70), . . . *ln*(24.04/30.63).

Calculate the standard deviation of the series,

> *sd* = 0.07325

Keep in mind that this is a simple method, and it does not allow for *skewness* or *kurtosis* in the frequency distribution of returns, but neither does the Black-Scholes option pricing model.

Comment: As he said it is a private company ...